# Create a column 'Date' with default value current datetime MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Following is my SQL query, it throws an error:-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS USER_PROFILE(Id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, date DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW) ;
```

It says `Invalid default value for 'date'`.

I've tried synonyms for `NOW()` as well, namely `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, but still the same error.

How can I create a column date with default value current time?

On the documentation page, it says to assign this way

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  dt DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

Comment: I changed my type to TIMESTAMP and it worked, but now I'm stucked upon creating an index. My query is `CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS LINK_INDEX on Table(url_hash,content_hash,date_)`. If I execute it woithout `IF NOT EXISTS`, it works fine. Whats the issue>?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the document

> The DEFAULT value clause in a data type specification indicates a
>   default value for a column. With one exception, the default value must
>   be a constant; it cannot be a function or an expression. This means,
>   for example, that you cannot set the default for a date column to be
>   the value of a function such as NOW() or CURRENT_DATE. The exception
>   is that you can specify CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as the default for TIMESTAMP
>   and DATETIME columns

So no function is allowed in the default value hence the first query is failing.

Again from the document

> As of MySQL 5.6.5, TIMESTAMP and DATETIME columns can be automatically
>   initializated and updated to the current date and time (that is, the
>   current timestamp). Before 5.6.5, this is true only for TIMESTAMP, and
>   for at most one TIMESTAMP column per table. The following notes first
>   describe automatic initialization and updating for MySQL 5.6.5 and up,
>   then the differences for versions preceding 5.6.5.

```
Before 5.6.5, this is true only for TIMESTAMP
```

So your mysql version is less than `5.6.5` hence the 2nd query is failing too.

So you need to create the table as

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 
USER_PROFILE
(
  Id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ;
```

Comment: I changed my type to TIMESTAMP and it worked, but now I'm stucked upon creating an index. My query is `CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS LINK_INDEX on Table(url_hash,content_hash,date_)`. If I execute it woithout `IF NOT EXISTS`, it works fine. Whats the issue>?

Comment: I usually do as `alter table table_name add index some_index_name(col1,col2)` you may try the same. Check the doc here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-index.html `if not exists` does not supported yet

Answer (score 0):

It might be that DATE, as a reserved word, is confusing it by the time it gets to the DEFAULT clause.  Try a different name and if that works, try quoting "date".

Comment: I changed my type to TIMESTAMP and it worked, but now I'm stucked upon creating an index. My query is `CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS LINK_INDEX on Table(url_hash,content_hash,date_)`. If I execute it woithout `IF NOT EXISTS`, it works fine. Whats the issue>?