# mysql date vs datetime default values

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create table with `date` filed and set its default value to `now()`

To my surprise, it does not work. I get

> Error #1067 - Invalid default value for 'xyz'

BUT. If I try to give this field a `datetime` type instead, it does accept `now()` as default value!

Same result if I try to use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` as default value. `datetime` takes it but `date` does not.

Now I have two questions:
1) Why?
2) How to make it work?

Before you answer: I found similar question here: 
[Create a column 'Date' with default value current datetime MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28966698/create-a-column-date-with-default-value-current-datetime-mysql) But it accepted answer does not say much. It only quotes MySQL documentation confirming it is like that but does not say why is it like that. And it does not say how to work around it, it just suggest using different type instead.

EDIT: seems like answer to question 2 is that it is not possible. But that makes me wonder even more why. Why does it make such a difference between date and datetime

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CURRENT_DATE` (an alias for `CURDATE()`) to get the current date. It does not take `now()` and `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` because those have a time component too, while this only contains the date part.

If you would like to use this in the `default` clause of SQL, you *can't*. You must use a trigger for it, if you need this. The reasons for this are unknown to me, so I would not like to speculate on it too much. However, I have a feeling this is *"yet another MySQL bug™"*.

Comment: same as rahautos's answer. you can put now() into date field in insert or update statement and it works. 

But thanks for telling me it cant be done. I kind of expected it based on documentation, i just can not believe it. I would still like to know why trough.

Answer (score 0):

CURDATE() will give current date while NOW() will give full date time.

```
SELECT NOW(); // You will get date time
SELECT CURDATE(); // You will get date
```

Your problem is your date time format

**if you column type is Date use  CURDATE()

if you column type is Datetime use  NOW()**

Comment: you can put now() into date field in insert or update statement and it works. so this should not be problem.

Moreover, select CURDATE() gives me date, but when it is in create table statement it is marked as syntax error (does not matter what type field is).